# Visual Studio 2012 installation (Access Denied)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

While installing Visual Studio 2012 in Windows 7 64-bit, the computer restarted (power failure), and after the install the folder "d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0" was gone. Now every time I run the installer, it starts installing and 5 seconds later I get the following message:

```
Setup Engine  
Access Denied
```

Does anyone know how to clean everything (all directories and registry) so I can start over from the beginning?

Comment: havent u tried running setup by run as admin?

Comment: @Vignesh4303 Yes no success I'm admin on this computer

Comment: Based upon your other question, can you confirm that this issue isn't with other types of installation - can you install, for example, Winamp or WinRar?

Comment: A power failure during an install will almost definitely leave corrupted files.  Are you able to manually create the folder?  You could also try something like Revo Uninstaller to remove any rogue registry entries.

Comment: I finally found fixed the problem. disabled all firewall/AV software and Anti-malware software. Install continued to run installation was corrupt after this. Did an uninstall an reinstall and now everything is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

1. Turn off the Antivirus temporarily.
2. Turn off Windows Firewall.
3. Clear `%temp%` folder.
4. Gave Full control permissions to *Everyone* and current logged in user (Admin one) role to following paths:

   - `C:\`
   - `C:\ProgramData`
   - `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache`

<sub>[`Reference here`](http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/2209/access-denied-in-visual-studio-ultimate-2012-installation-setup)</sub>

Comment: This worked just one problem don't have start menu items the folder VS2012 is empty

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had a corrupted installation of Rhino SDK, which also gave a similar error. I used an application called [CCLeaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) to clean associated registry files. It worked for me.